# How can a non-instantiated object be accessed via dot notation? (Swift Playground)

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm confused about the coordinate.column and coordinate.row used in the code swift plyground provided below. How was column and row accssed when I didn't instantiate the instance coordinate? If the for loop insatntiate coordinate, how was it instantiated when allcoordinates or world.allPossibleCoordinates are not a type? (There are no parathenthesis around world.allPossibleCoordinates...)

```
let allCoordinates = world.allPossibleCoordinates
var blockSet: [Coordinate] = []

//#-editable-code Tap to enter code
for coordinate in allCoordinates {
    // Check for coordinates with a column > 5 OR a row < 4.
    if coordinate.column > 2 && coordinate.row < 5 {
        // Append coordinate to blockSet.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Swift`, the `for in` loop works a bit differently than a `for` loop in other languages. A `for in` loop strides over a range (I'm assuming allCoordinates is strideable). In the provided example, if the variable allCoordinates is a strideable range, the loop will go through every single item in that range assigning each value to `coordinate` per iteration. For more information, have a look at [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html)

Comment: Thx I understand this concept but not how the dot notation can be applied to the coordinate. How is the column and row predefined for coordinate?

Comment: If the `Coordinate` is a `class` or a `struct`, you can access its properties using dot notation. It's pretty standard practice. So the `for in` loop iterates over an array of objects where each object has these two attributes. Hope that makes it clear